# Link to CPanel from templates

Tags: templates, cpanel

From my templates, I want to link to my CPanel. The template is only accessible by those who do have permission to access the CPanel. How do I link to the CPanel from the template? The URL I see generated when I log in seems to include a session id.

Comment: to what pages you want to make links?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from version 2.8.0 you can use standard [global variable](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/single_variables.html#cp-session-id) for this

```
{cp_session_id}
```

if you want to make link to edit entry, don't forget about special tag for this which [available from version 2.9.0](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#cp-edit-entry-url)

```
{cp_edit_entry_url}
```

You can also [output the cp main url](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/single_variables.html#cp-url) (like example.com/admin.php) using global variable (from ee 2.8.0)

```
{cp_url}
```

Comment: So what is the URL? Do I have to build it, adding the session id in the query string?

Comment: URL to what? You still don't tell what page you need. If entry - <a href="{cp_edit_entry_url}">Edit Entry</a>. If some other page - copy url from CP, replace session_id  with tag + you can replace main cp url with {cp_url}. Or you just want url to CP at is?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the session id via PHP by using

```
$this->EE->session->userdata['session_id']
```

You are probably best wrapping this in a plugin